# Suppose $N\unlhd G$ with $N\cong G/N\cong S$, $S$ a nonabelian finite simple group. Assume that $\operatorname{Out}(S)$ is solvable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, simple-groups, solvable-groups

I am given a group $G$ and a normal subgroup $N$ such that both $N$ and $G/N$ are isomorphic to $S$, a nonabelian finite simple group. I am also told to assume that $\operatorname{Out}(S)$ is solvable. Here is what I have shown so far:

1. $C_G (N) = \{ g \in G : gn = ng \ \forall n \in N \}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$  (by showing that it is the kernel of a group homomorphism from $G$ to $\operatorname{Aut}(N)$)
2. $N \cap C_G (N) = 1$ (by showing that it is an abelian normal subgroup of $N$)
3. $\operatorname{Inn}(N) \cong S$ (by defining a homomorphism from $N$ to $\operatorname{Inn}(N)$, with trivial kernel)

Now I am asked to show that

- $C_G(N) \neq 1$, using the facts that $\operatorname{Out}(S)$ is solvable, $\operatorname{Inn}(N)$ is a normal subgroup of the image of a the homomorphism I defined in (1), and the Jordan-Holder theorem.
- $G = NC_G(N)$, I suspect using the fact that $C_G(N)$ contains a non-identity element?

Any direction would be great. If, for instance, I can show that if $C_G(N) = 1$ then $\operatorname{Out}(S) \cong G/N$, I will be done. But I don't see how to do this. The only other thing I can think of would be to show that $C_G(N)$ is composition factor of $\operatorname{Out}(S)$, which would mean it would be cyclic of prime order and therefore have at least 2 elements.

Comment: what does the title of the question have to do with the body?

Comment: Sorry - I got very off track in writing this post. It would be useful in proving that $G = N C_G (N)$, since both $N$ and $C_G(N)$ are both normal subgroups of $G$ and their intersection is trivial.

Comment: Oh I see, the statement in the title is not necessarily true though.

Comment: Sigh- I figured. Thanks.

Comment: In the first sentence you say $G$ is isomorphic to $S$, which implies $G$ is simple, so $N=\{1\}$ or $G$. Did you instead mean to say that $N$ is isomorphic to $S$?

Comment: Yes- thank you. $N$ and $G/N$ are both isomorphic to S.

Comment: Hint for the first one: if $G\to\mathrm{Aut}(N)$ is injective then $G/N\to\mathrm{Out}(N)$ is injective, and any subgroup of a solvable group is solvable.

Comment: I think I figured out the second part. We have that $(G/N)/(NC_G(N)/C_G(N)) \cong G/NC_G(N)$, and also that $NC_G(N)/C_G(N)\cong N$, so since $G/N \cong S$ and $N \cong S$, then $G/NC_G(N) \cong 1 \Rightarrow G = NC_G(N)$.